# How to navigate from stack navigator to tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

Once Logged in, a TabNav is present, from 1st tab i navigate to second tab and then i navigate to a screen defined in StackNav now i want to navigate to 3rd Tab in TabNav. How to achieve this? I want to "fetch" data from the server which is not happening coz the "componentDidMount" is not getting called.

I had the same issue when i had to navigate from TabNav to StackNav but i solved it by defining TabNav inside StackNav.

This is my App.js

```
export class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: Screen1,
  },
});

const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Second: {
    screen: Screen2,
  },
});

const Screen3_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Third: {
    screen: Screen3,
  },
});

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
{
  Upcoming: { screen: UpcomingScreen },
  Accepted: { screen: AcceptedScreen },
  Ongoing: { screen: OngoingScreen },
  Completed: { screen: CompletedScreen },
},
);

const tabs = createStackNavigator({
 Root: {
 screen: TabNavigator,
 navigationOptions: () => ({
  title: `Welcome, John Doe`,
 }),
},
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
  login: 
    {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
      }),
    },

  login: Login,
  tab: tabs,
  acceptedTrip: AcceptedTrip,
  startTrip: StartTrip,

  upload: Upload,
  geoLoc: GeoLoc,
  ongoingScreen: OngoingScreen
},
{
 headerMode: 'none',
 navigationOptions: {
  headerVisible: false,
}
}
)

const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  Screen1: {
  screen: AppNavigator,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: 'Login',
  },
},

Screen2: {
  screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 2',
  },
},

Screen3: {
  screen: Screen3_StackNavigator,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 3',
  },
},
Screen4: {
  screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 1',
  },
},
},
{
 initialRouteName: "Screen1"
}
);

const MyApp = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);

class App extends React.Component{
render(){
  return <MyApp/>
}
}

export default App
```

the componentDidMount is not getting called.

Comment: I am doing this.props.navigation.navigate('Ongoing') from startTrip.js . startTrip.js is in Stack navigator , now i want to redirect from startTrip.js to "Ongoing" which is in 3rd tab of TabNav its redirecting but nothing gets displayed and componentDidMount is not called.

Comment: SOLUTION : My issue was the "componentDidMount" was not getting called 
the solution is in react-navigation itself. please follow below link

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html